# obtain geolocation position inside codeigniter controller

Tags: php, codeigniter, google-maps-api-3, geolocation

I would obtain using google maps api geolocation the value of latitude and longitude of my position and use this values inside my controller as simple php vars.do you know if does it exist some library,helper or some way to do what I need?

Comment: Have you tried looking at the docs? http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/webservices/index.html

Comment: @tkone I don't know how this could help me...

Comment: Have you read it's documentation?  It will explain what it does.

Answer (score 2):

one thing you should know is that GeoLocation API is browser/client-side thing. It is not possible to determine a more-accurate-then-ip location from the server-side.

to answer your question on how to "obtain GeoLocation position inside codeigniter controller" what you should do is try to pass the information from client-side to server-side.

One way to do this is via ajax. Here's an example flow:

1) User browses to your webpage (at this point you don't know the user's more-accuate-then-ip location yet)

2) You will prompt the user to share his location via the browser's [GeoLocation API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/W3C_Geolocation_API).

3) If the user allows you to know his location by clicking "share location" then you do an ajax call back to the server with the user's more-accurate-then-ip location.

4) Once you get that, you can then tell the client what to do in your ajax response.

P.S. you should also handle the flow where user chooses NOT to share his more-accuate-then-ip location with you via the GeoLocation API.

**UPDATE**

And like everyone else said just read the v3 gmap API.
it's simply something like

```
if (navigator.geolocation) var gl = navigator.geolocation;
if (gl) {
   gl.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
      alert(position.coords.latitude);
      alert(position.coords.longitude);
   }, function(positionError) {
      alert(positionError.message);
   });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at this [Google Maps API V3 Library](http://codeigniter.com/wiki/Google_Maps_API_V3_Library), the instructions are [here](http://www.in-the-attic.co.uk/2010/08/03/google-map-library-for-codeigniter-example-usage-update/) (look at the geocoding instructions)